# How do present-day originalists view the doctrine of desuetude?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, desuetude, theory-of-law

Do present-day [originalists](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/white-papers/on-originalism-in-constitutional-interpretation) in the US have a common viewpoint on [desuetude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desuetude#United_States_law)?

If not, what sub-schools of thought on this matter exist within originalism?

Comment: Why the DV? The long and rather contestested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Originalism doesn't mention the topic explicitly.

Comment: Because the two concepts are orthogonal?  Desuetude doesn't apply to the Constitution, so this seems more like a request for opinions than anything else.

Comment: I would that there probably isn't any consistent position on the issue particular to originalists. I can think of conservative jurists who claim to be originalists writing opinions that come down in opposite ways as the political bent of the cases or issues before them differ. Abhoring it, for example, when doing so provides a means to limit the constitutional rights of non-citizens, and accepting it when it provides a means to ignore the treaty rights of Indian tribes.

Comment: @cHao Originalism doesnt apply to only the constitution, it applies to all laws. So i'm not sure why Desuetude not applying to the constitution has any bearing on this.

Comment: You can be originalist about the constitution without being originalist about other laws; but by itself the term originalism in the US usually refers to the Constitution. So it seems sensible to interpret the question that way, unless the question explicitly refers to people who are originalist about other laws. [Cornell's website](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/originalism) says "Originalism is a theory of interpreting legal texts holding that a text in law, especially the U.S. Constitution, should be interpreted as it was understood at the time of its adoption."